# Page Crawling For this Python Script

Tags: python, web-crawler

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.cbssports.com/nhl/stats/playersort/nhl/year-2017-season-preseason-category-goals')
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv("20172018PreseasonData.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

I am Trying to Crawl the 1-17 pages all at once. When I run this, although the link i am on is "All" it still only crawls page 1. I would like 1-17 all on the same csv. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the page source code (right click on the page and hit inspect if in google chrome) you will see that the actual link to the 'ALL' page is `https://www.cbssports.com/nhl/stats/playersort/nhl/year-2017-season-preseason-category-goals?print_rows=9999` as shown in the highlighted row in the picture below.

[image]